# 404 not found for asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I am getting 404 not found status codes for my minified javascripts files and also there is an error ASP.Net ajax client side framework failed to load.

I have given my configuration settings in the web.config below,

```
 <httpModules>
      <!-- Component Art-->
      <add type="ComponentArt.Web.UI.UploadModule,ComponentArt.Web.UI" name="ComponentArtUploadModule"/>
      <!--Blog Engine-->
      <add name="WwwSubDomainModule" type="BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpModules.WwwSubDomainModule, BlogEngine.Core"/>
      <add name="UrlRewrite" type="BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpModules.UrlRewrite, BlogEngine.Core"/>
      <add name="CompressionModule" type="BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpModules.CompressionModule, BlogEngine.Core"/>
      <add name="ReferrerModule" type="BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpModules.ReferrerModule, BlogEngine.Core"/>
      <!--Remove the default ASP.NET modules we don't need-->
      <remove name="PassportAuthentication"/>
      <remove name="Profile"/>
      <remove name="AnonymousIdentification"/>
    </httpModules>
<system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>

        <modules>
            <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v10.2, Version=10.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"/>
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <add name="ComponentArtScriptHandler" type="ComponentArt.Web.UI.ScriptHandler,ComponentArt.Web.UI" path="ComponentArtScript.axd" verb="*" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
```

I cant figure out whether I am missing any configuration or added something extra. Can somebody have a look

Comment: Is the Url from which it is requesting the script resource valid? May be it is not resolving to the path which you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting "not found" error, there's something wrong with resolving the path. Either the path/file doesn't exist (because it's somewhere else for instance), or you have some conflicting rules in rewrite/routing engine.

Try to use, as a temporary fix, absolute paths. That means instead of

```
href="../../my.js"
```

you'd write

```
href="http://mypage.com/js/my.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @walther

```
href="/js/my.js"
```

As the first slash will take the path to the root of the URL, so useful for when moving between different environments (provided your dev isn't in a subfolder).